# How can I construct binomial terms using the Binomial function?

Tags: functions, combinatorics

I want to construct a table of the terms

```
Binomial[n, i] t^i (1-t)^(n-i)
```

where `i` goes from 0 to `n`.

I do not want to sum them. I want all the individual terms in a list. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Why does the code that you show not work in a `Table`? `n = 5; Table[Binomial[n, i]*t^i*(1 - t)^(n - i), {i, 0, n}]`

Comment: @Szaboics : it's not the code, basically I can only come up with the binomial coefficients, and I do not know how to combine and multiply the t and (1-t) terms

Comment: `Apply[List, (x + y)^10 // Expand] /. {x -> t, y -> 1 - t}`

Answer (score 1):

As Szabolcs suggests, if you want a listing of all the terms, then you can use Table

```
n = 3; Table[Binomial[n, i] t^i (1 - t)^(n - i), {i, 0, n}]
{(1 - t)^3, 3 (1 - t)^2 t, 3 (1 - t) t^2, t^3}
```

or you can use Map (the symbols /@) to achieve the same thing:

```
n = 3; Binomial[n, #] t^# (1 - t)^(n - #) & /@ Range[0, n]
```